# Can I use a 16amp 250w EU plug in a converter plug which says 13amp in the uk?

Tags: electrical, socket

I recently bought a NutriBullet which has an EU plug on it. The plug says 16a 250v.

I have an adapter to use it in the uk but it says 13a on it. Can I plug it in and use it with the adapter? I can’t find any adapters with more than 13a.

Answer (score 5):

I would chop off the EU plug and fit a classic 13A UK plug to the cable. This has the advantage that the UK plug is fused and you can fit a more appropriate fuse for the size of the appliance.

I do this for items I take to Switzerland and for items I bring back.

Neither country has items that take more power than 13A so it's fine, I do check the wattage stated on the device but monitors, fans, kitchen blenders etc are lower than 13A in terms of actual use. The one I would be worried about is my big welder but that won't be moving anyway.

Comment: This.  **You NEED to use a UK plug with a fuse**, because it is potentially going into 32A ring mains. The UK safety scheme **relies** on each appliance having a fuse sized appropriately for it. On the continent they design appliances to reliably trip a 13A or 16A breaker.  It's not designed or tested to trip a 32A, it could just sit there burning.

Comment: In the UK, domestic appliances are to be fused at a maximum of 13amps at the plug socket, so you won't find a 16amp plug in the UK. Electric cookers wired into a spur are different, but even plug-in electric cookers have to conform to the same principle. When wiring the UK plug, just be sure to wire the live wire to the fuse and the neutral to the other side. The top pin is for an earthing wire.

Answer (score 1):

The most powerful Nutribullet I can find online uses about 1700 Watts.

That's absolutely fine on a UK 13A circuit. In broad terms, 3kW [3000 watts] is considered a safe maximum on a regular socket with nothing else in the same socket [no extension leads etc].

Make sure the adapter is a firm fit - no wobbles, no sparks. If not, replace the plug with a proper UK 13A.

Answer (score 1):

The rating stamped on a plug is the rating of the plug. It does not represent the rating of anything else.

The appliance should have a plate or sticker indicating its requirements. Most appliances will be fine with the slightly lower rated UK plug, but you do need to check.

If more than 13A is needed, then you can't use a normal UK socket and other arrangements would be needed to supply the appliance.

For permanent use in the UK, replacing the plug is preferable to using an adapter, there are less connections to go wrong and less stress is placed on the socket since the correct a plug is smaller and lighter than a combination of plug and adapter.

If you do use an adapter make sure you get the right adapter. That means the adapter should be.

1. Fused with a BS1362 fuse.
2. From a reputable vendor, sadly there is a lot of dangerous garbage out there sold through marketplace sites like Ebay and Amazon.
3. Specifically designed for the plug and socket types involved. Many travel adapters try to generalize to multiple plug and socket types, but this leads to problems like poor fits and lost earths.